# How can I create a link_to with newly def

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up new def like this:

```
  def info
    @book = Book.find(params[:id])
  end
```

and im trying to link it using this:

```
<%= link_to 'info', info_book_path %>
```

so the url should look like this `localhost:3000/books/13/info`
(13 is an id of a book)

Any idea? thanks!

Comment: You need to pass it the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your routes you need to define the info path:

```
resources :books do
  member do
    get :info
  end
end
```

Then you will have the helper method

```
info_book_path(book)
```

More information on [the railsguides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#regular-routes)